# Retrieve values using a self join query

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve records where the albumid is not found on the parent_albumid and where the parent_albumid is NULL

example:

```
albumid       name         parent_albumid
------------------------------------------------------
145           sun          NULL
146           fly          145
148           ok           NULL
149           mama         148
150           test         NULL
```

In the example above, albumid 145 and 148 are in the parent_albumid, so there are out. Record 146 and 149 have a parent_albumid, so there are out.... albumid 150 is the one left, the one that should be return by the result set

I was able to experiment using the self join query, but that doesn't help me at all!

```
SELECT a.albumid, a.name, a.parent_albumid
FROM album AS a
JOIN album AS b on a.albumid = b.parent_albumid
```

How do i create my self join query?

Comment: exactly how are you going to tell between #145 and #150? They both have a parent ID of `null`, so what makes 145 "ok" and 150 "bad"?

Comment: 150 is the ok and 145 is the bad...

Comment: Are you aware with self Joni,inner join,outer join........

Comment: @JegsVala no im not, that's why im asking here.. im a newbie

Comment: You can use outer join because if you want to get result with match record and all other record which has null value.

Comment: @Marco Did you look at my answer?

Comment: @plalx: yes i did! i've tested both and the 2nd looks a bit faster, for some reason... first query, i get an average of 0.00051 and the second an average of 0.00042. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but here's one:

```
SELECT a.albumid
FROM album a
WHERE 
    parent_albumid IS NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM album
        WHERE parent_albumid = a.albumid
    )
```

Here's another one (I prefer the first which indicates better the intention):

```
SELECT a1.albumid
FROM album a1
LEFT JOIN album a2
    ON a2.parent_albumid = a1.albumid
WHERE a1.parent_albumid IS NULL AND a2.albumid IS NULL
```